# Create composite type with default values

Tags: julia

How can I define a composite type

```
mutable struct Foo
    bar::Int64
end
```

such that when I create an instance of it, `bar` gets a default value, let's say `42`?

I know I can create the instance with

```
Foo(42)
```

but I would like to do something like

```
Foo()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just define a constructor with a default value:

```
julia> struct Foo; bar::Int64; end

julia> Foo() = Foo(42)
Foo

julia> Foo()
Foo(42)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Base.@kwdef](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/util.jl#L388-L504) like so:

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct Foo
    bar::Int64 = 42
end
```

```
julia> foo = Foo()
Foo(42)

julia> foo.bar
42

julia> foo = Foo(bar = 423)
Foo(423)

julia> foo.bar
423
```

And if you need more functionality, then you could check out a package called [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl)

Answer (score 0):

For information on how to implement various constructors you can check out the documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/